# Need to utilize OpenNETCF v2.x Imaging in application that has assemblies built on OpenNETCF v1.4

Tags: .net, compact-framework, imaging, opennetcf

I have an existing WM application that I need to capture photos with and it looks like the Imaging class in OpenNETCF v2.x is the best bet because I am running into the "Out of memory" exception when simply trying to open the files. The application is built on a vendor's mobility platform and it appears that their assemblies leverage OpenNETCF v1.4 (which I don't have access to to recompile them with the newer version of OpenNETCF). When I simply add a reference to the new version of OpenNETCF, the mobile solution fails to run. Is there a way to reference multiple versions of the OpenNETCF library or am I stuck in the water? Or is there a way to create a class library for the imaging part of it that does not require a reference to the new OpenNETCF libraries in the base application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple options.

1. Put the newer SDF files in the same folder as your app.  The loader should look there first and resolve your references.  If it looks in \Windows first and pulls the 1.4 bits, you could always force the issue by calling `Assembly.LoadFrom` early on and making it load the local 2.3 versions.
2. Compile the Imaging pieces from the 2.3 code base directly into your assembly.

Comment: Thanks @ctacke, I implemented option two and got it up and running.